# Rails ActionController ignores request headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors, ruby-on-rails-5, rack, rack-cors

I have a simple controller method that logs headers via ActionController's #headers method:

```
class ThingsController < ActionController::Base
  def show
    Rails.logger.info headers
    render json: {response: 'success'}
  end
end
```

However, when I call this controller method via curl with headers, they are not logged:

```
curl "http://localhost:3000/things/1” \
  -H "access-token XXX" \
  -H "token-type Bearer" \
  -H "client YYY" \
  -H "expiry 1234" \
  -H "uid test@test" \
```

Instead, the following headers are logged:

```
{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff"}
```

I thought my Rails 5 app's CORS policy might be to blame, so I installed the rack-cors gem and configured it in the initializer below. Unfortunately, it did not change the result.

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: %i(get post put patch delete options head)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with CORS.

In Rails 5.2, the ActionController instance method `#headers` is delegated to the `response` object.
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.0/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal.rb#L150

```ruby
delegate :headers, :status=, :location=, :content_type=,
         :status, :location, :content_type, to: "@_response"
```

To access the request headers, you can do so via the `request` object. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-headers

Additionally, your cURL syntax needs to change to delimit the key from the value.

```
curl "http://localhost:3000/things/1” \
  -H "access-token: XXX" \
  -H "token-type: Bearer" \
  -H "client: YYY" \
  -H "expiry: 1234" \
  -H "uid: test@test" \
```

Per the [Rack spec](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/file/SPEC.rdoc#label-The+Environment) (and [RFC 3875](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-4.1.18)), headers sent by the client are prefixed with `HTTP_` and all occurrences of `-` are replaced with `_`.

To log the headers you specified via cURL:

```
class ThingsController < ActionController::Base
  def show
    Rails.logger.info {
      request.headers.env.slice(
        "HTTP_ACCESS_TOKEN",
        "HTTP_TOKEN_TYPE",
        "HTTP_CLIENT",
        "HTTP_EXPIRY",
        "HTTP_UID"
      )
    }
    render json: {response: 'success'}
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Great answer.